# Java server receiving files from a large number of clients

Tags: java, client-server, nio

I am designing a java server that needs to be able to maintain connections with a large number of clients(possibly several thousand) and recive a single PDF file from each these clients. These PDFs will be relativly short(at most 10-15 pages), but all the transfers will 
take place in a short timeframe. From what i understand socket programming is the way to go. What technology is best suited to use for the server?

So far it seems java.nio, possibly trough MINA or Netty, is the best option. Am i missing something?

Comment: There are plenty of implementations that can do this for you. Why are you designing your own?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Java Servlet Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) here. In this manner you won't be rewriting its multithreading capability from scratch since the application server / servlet container will handle it for you. Plus you will be on top of TCP/IP which is convenient.

In case you're not exposed to this technology, just override the service or doPost method. Read the incoming stream, reconstruct the PDF data then write to a file or save it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you will handle several requests at once you will need a multithread aproach (here is a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm))
For the file handling a simple tcp/ip server should be sufficient something like this [example](http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/WWW/examples/FileServer.java)